# Spring REST based Apache Common file upload not works

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I want to upload multi files.

but it not works..

my source.

pom.xml

```
<!-- commons-io (fileupload dependency) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<!-- fileupload -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>multipartResolverBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>filterMultipartResolver</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

root-context.xml

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000" />
</bean>
```

jsp file (method is POST or PUT. but both not works)

```
<form:form commandName="community" action="${CONTEXT }/community/${community.no}" method="${method}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <img src="" name="titleImage" id="titleImage"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" name="titleImageFile"/>
    <br/>
    title
    <form:input path="title" id="title" title="title"/><form:errors path="title"/>
    <br/>
    <form:textarea path="content" rows="5" cols="30"/>
    <br/>
    <img src="" name="contentImage" id="contentImage"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="file" name="contentImageFile"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="ok" onclick="showProgressBar()"/>
</form:form>
```

controller

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@RequestMapping(value = "/{no}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String insert(HttpServletRequest request
        , @Valid Community community
        , BindingResult bindingResult
        , SessionStatus sessionStatus
        , ModelMap model)
{
    System.out.println("IN POST>>>@@@");
    System.out.println("IN POST>>>@@@");
    System.out.println("IN POST>>>@@@");
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
    {
        return showWriteForm(model);
    }
    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("community", community);
    System.out.println("isMultipart?::"+ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    fileUpload.setSizeMax(-1);

    List<FileItem> items = null;
    try {
        items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("items size :: "+items.size());
    communityService.insert(map);
    return "redirect:/community/"+community.getNo();
}
```

why items size 0?

help please...

I'm using RESTFUL design, Spring MVC, Spring-Security, Commons-io, Commons-fileupload, jstl, Spring Form tag, JSTL... what's wrong?

Comment: Does the running process have write access to whatever directory is returned by System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")?

Comment: my java.io.tmpdir is
C:\Users\slbi\AppData\Local\Temp\
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
and log4j debug dir :: 
CommonsMultipartResolver - Found multipart file [titleImageFile] of size 879394 bytes with original filename [Chrysanthemum.jpg], stored at [C:\Users\slbi\EEworkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\cinemadream\upload__775585f1_1432352e2dc__7ffe_00000000.tmp]

Comment: running process have write access my java.io.tmpdir. not problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the request directly, then you have to use `MultipartHttpServletRequest`. But I suggest to use `MultipartFile`:

```
public String insert(@Valid Community community,
                     @RequestParam MultipartFile titleImageFile,
                     @RequestParam MultipartFile contentImageFile
```

Comment: please read my new question..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755823/multipart-request-not-initialized-exception